# akka http error while calling lagom streaming service

Tags: lagom

I am following [this](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/java/ServiceImplementation.html).

Code snippet is as:

```
public ServerServiceCall<String, Source<String, ?>> tick(int intervalMs) {
  return tickMessage -> {
    Duration interval = Duration.ofMillis(intervalMs);
    return completedFuture(Source.tick(interval, interval, tickMessage));
 };
}
```

But when I try to hit service: http://localhost:9000/tick/2000, I get HTTP error 500.

Background traces are available [here](https://pastebin.com/4yE5H7P0)

Comment: Can you should your Guice module? It seems like your `Source` isn't being materialized.

Comment: Hi, I couldn't get what action you want me to take.Can you please explain again?

Comment: You need a module to do dependency injection. Something like [this](https://github.com/lagom/online-auction-java/blob/master/bidding-impl/src/main/java/Module.java).